# tengo este codigo y tengo dudas de como hacer un metodo que me permita ordenar los numeros de mayor a menor cuando seleccione el usuario "mostrar"

Tags: python, vscode

```
class NodoB:

    def __init__(self, dato):
     self.elemento=dato
     self.siguiente=None
    def MostrarDato(self):
       return self.elemento

class ListaB:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        self.tam=0
    def insertar (self,v):
        nodo=NodoB(v)
        if self.tam==0:
            self.head=nodo
        else:
            p=self.head
            for i in range (self.tam-1):
                p=p.siguiente
            p.siguiente=nodo
        self.tam+=1
        
    def mostrar(self):
        x=self.head
        for i in range (self.tam):
            print(x.MostrarDato())
            x=x.siguiente

    def eliminar(self,v):
        m=self.buscar(v)
        if m==-1:
            print("error elemento no encontrado")
        else:
            if self.tam==0:
                self.head=self.head.siguiente
                self.tam-=1
            else:
                p=self.head
                for i in range(m-1):
                   p=p.siguiente
                   p.siguiente=p.siguiente.siguiente
                   self.tam-=1

    def buscar(self,v):
        p=self.head
        t=0
        for i in range (self.tam):
            if p.MostrarDato()==v:
                return t
            p=p.siguiente
            t+=1
        if t==self.tam:
         t=-1
        return t
    def eliminar2(self):
        self.head=self.head.siguiente

    
p=ListaB()
while True: 
    opcion=int(input("[1]_Insertar\n[2]_Mostrar\n[3]_Eliminar\n[4]_Buscar registro\n[5]_Ordenar registro\nelija una opcion ="))
    if opcion==1:
       print("insertar") 
       v=input("ingresa un valor = ")
       p.insertar(v)    
    if opcion==2:
        print("Mostrar")
        p.mostrar()
    if opcion==3:
         l=int(input("elige que registro deseas eliminar"))
         p.eliminar(l)  
    if opcion ==4:
         v=int(input("selecciona el numero que quieres encontrar = "))
         p.buscar(v)
    if opcion == 5:
            p.ordenar()
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Cómo tú mismo dices, el problema es como ordenar los elementos de una lista enlazada. Por tanto, todo el código de insertar, mostrar, eliminar, buscar, etc. está de más. No es relevante al problema. Lo mejor es reemplantear la pregunta "¿Cómo ordeno esta lista enlazada?" y reduce el código sólo a eso.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con el método `sort` que te ordena una lista de números.

Por ejemplo:

```
numeros = [16, 4, 9, 1, 3, 20, 8]
numeros.sort()
```

Lo puedes adaptar a la forma en la que recoges los valores a ordenar en tú código y sobre ellos haces el `sort`

Comment: Nota: sort y sorted NO se limitan solo a listas de numeros. Permiten ordenar de forma personalizada una lista y (solo en caso de sorted) cualquier secuencia.

Answer (score 0):

Si el problema se reduce a **mostrarla ordenada** , lo que puedes hacer es en la función `mostrar` crear una lista (python) auxiliar a la que metas todos los elementos de la lista enlazada, y después uses la función `sorted()` de Python para ordenarla.

Si en cambio lo que quieres es **ordenar la lista enlazada**, no creo que eso deba hacerlo la función `mostrar()`, sino que deberías implementar una función `ordenar()` que lo haga. Para ello sería útil tener una función que pueda intercambiar dos elementos de la lista entre sí, o insertar un elemento entre otros dos, dependiendo de qué algoritmo de ordenación decidas usar. Este problema puede ser bastante complicado, especialmente con tu actual implementación de la lista, y quizás fuera más sencillo mantener la lista ordenada cuando insertas un dato en ella (en vez de inserta un elemento al final, lo insertas justo delante del primero que sea mayor a él).

En todo caso, ya que en la pregunta únicamente te refieres a **mostrar la lista ordenada**, responderé a esta cuestión. Puedes ampliar en un comentario la pregunta si quieres que responda a cómo ordenarla.

### Mostrar la lista ordenada

Como dije antes, puedes crear una lista (python) auxiliar y ordenarla para imprimirla. Así:

```
    def mostrar(self):
      lista = []
      # Recopilar los elementos
      x = self.head
      for i in range(self.tam):
        lista.append(x.MostrarDato())
        x = x.siguiente

      # Imprimirlos en orden de mayor a menor
      for elem in sorted(lista, reversed=True):
        print(elem)
```

**Nota**. Yo cambiaría el nombre del método `MostrarDato()` a `get_dato()`. Para empezar el método no muestra nada, simplemente retorna el valor, es decir, es claramente un *getter*. Además no sigue el convenio python de que los nombres de método deben ir en minúsculas y en `snake_case`